# How do I implement a progress bar

Tags: jupyter-notebook

How do I implement a progress bar in jupyter-notebook?

I've done this:

```py
count = 0
max_count = 100
bar_width = 40
while count <= max_count:
    time.sleep(.1)
    b = bar_width * count / max_count
    l = bar_width - b
    print '\r' + u"\u2588" * b + '-' * l,
    count += 1
```

Which is great when I have access to a loop in which to print stuff out.  But does anyone know of anything clever to run a progress bar of some sort asynchronously?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Take a look at this open-source widget: [log-process](https://github.com/alexanderkuk/log-progress)

Answer (score 65):

Here is a solution (following [this](http://jgardiner.co.uk/blog/jupyter_progress_bar)).

```py
from ipywidgets import IntProgress
from IPython.display import display
import time

max_count = 100

f = IntProgress(min=0, max=max_count) # instantiate the bar
display(f) # display the bar

count = 0
while count <= max_count:
    f.value += 1 # signal to increment the progress bar
    time.sleep(.1)
    count += 1
```

If the value that's changing in the loop is a `float` instead of an `int`, you can use `ipwidgets.FloatProgress` instead.

Comment: Very handy. But it you're incrementing an integer why not use [`IntProgress`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#IntProgress) instead?

Comment: Probably mostly ignorance! :)

Comment: The link you posted seems broken @StephenMcAteer

Comment: For me this just shows `IntProgress(value=0, max=10)` without showing an actual progress bar.

Answer (score 41):

You can try [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm). Example code:

```
# pip install tqdm
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

# works on any iterable, including cursors. 
# for iterables with len(), no need to specify 'total'.
for rec in tqdm_notebook(items, 
                         total=total, 
                         desc="Processing records"):
    # any code processing the elements in the iterable
    len(rec.keys())
```

Demo:
https://youtu.be/T0gmQDgPtzY

Comment: I want this, but I want it to work with just regular tqdm so that I can import my code and run it natively or in a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: @EricHansen, try: `from tqdm.auto import tqdm`. It will try to automatically detect whether you are running in a notebook, or in a text console.

Comment: As of July 2021, `tqdm.auto` still does not detect if you are running in a vscode notebook and will use default console output. If you are running in vscode and experiencing this bug, use `tqdm.notebook` instead.

Answer (score 24):

In August 2020, the [log-process](https://github.com/kuk/log-progress) widget is no longer an appropriate method to apply as it has been integrated into [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm). The first tutorial example (using the new API) works out-of-the-box in VSCode, and I suspect it will work nicely in Jupyter as well.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    pass
```

[image: vscode notebook example]

**Update Febuary 2021:**

Tqdm attempts to detect whether or not you're in a notebook, and tries to select the appropriate type of progress bar accordingly. It does so through a module `tqdm.auto`. I've observed cases where `tqdm.auto` selects the command-line variant (shown above) in a VSCode notebook rather than the `tqdm.notebook` variant.

This often has no ill effects, but can occsionally cause *extremely verbose scrolling output*. I've seen this occur while training tensorflow models in VSCode noteboks. Consequently, I'd recommend:

1. `from tqdm import tqdm` - in library code or scripts
2. `from tqdm.notebook import tqdm` - in notebooks

Comment: This is really nice and no additional lines of code required, thanks!

Comment: from tqdm.notebook import tqdm.

I have the progress bar just below the cell and I have printing below the progress bar. This is  Perfect !!!

Comment: Works great and elegant.

Answer (score 8):

**Another Example for Progress Bar using tqdm**

```
    from tqdm import tqdm
    my_list = list(range(100))
    with tqdm(total=len(my_list)) as pbar:
      for x in my_list:
          pbar.update(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used ipywidgets and threading to implement a progress bar for the duration of a method call, see the example below

```py
import threading
import time
import ipywidgets as widgets
def method_I_want_progress_bar_for():   
    progress = widgets.FloatProgress(value=0.0, min=0.0, max=1.0)
    finished = False
    def work(progress):#method local to this method
        total = 200
        for i in range(total):
            if finished != True:
                time.sleep(0.2)
                progress.value = float(i+1)/total
            else:
                progress.value = 200
                break

    thread = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(progress,))
    display(progress)
    #start the progress bar thread
    thread.start()

    #Whatever code you want to run async

    finished = True #To set the process bar to 100% and exit the thread
```

Answer (score 1):

[`progressbar-2`](https://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a modern library with some powerful features.

```py
import time
import progressbar

for i in progressbar.progressbar(range(100)):
    time.sleep(0.02)
```