# How to track the progress of python execution on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, logging, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am running a program with huge data set on ipython jupyter notebook and the notation **ln [*]** for the same cell block remains the same for longer time. I would like to trace the progress of my execution. In the sense, need to look at any logs to understand the pause of kernel; Is this a genuine halt of kernel or something really stuck and i need to make changes on program and kernel resources ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861829/how-do-i-implement-a-progress-bar

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of this add-ins online. If you are using for loops, you can use this one https://github.com/alexanderkuk/log-progress

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It will be helpful