# Displaying message during lengthy cell execution

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a jupyter notebook in which one cell takes a while to produce a series of graphs. To reassure users that the platform isn't malfunctioning and the cell isn't frozen I'd like to do something like `print('computing')` every 5 seconds until the cell finishes executing.

Is there a straightforward way to do this in the jupyter notebook environment? I've explored some of the native timing functionality and it doesn't appear as though there's anything that quite does this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I implement a progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861829/how-do-i-implement-a-progress-bar)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#module-threading) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) to do this, I used threading below.

```py
import time
from threading import Thread

def progress(stop):
    while True:
        print('Cell Running...')
        time.sleep(5)
        if stop():
            break

stop_threads = False
t1 = Thread(target=progress, args=(lambda: stop_threads, ))
t1.start()

# do main here
print('from main')
time.sleep(6)
print('from main 2')
stop_threads = True

# join your thread
t1.join()
```

Comment: Are you this code runs without error. False() gives error. And I could not install threading package. What be the cause?

Comment: Remove the () that is a mistake in typing. Sorry

Comment: Threading is default in python so I’m not sure why you couldn’t import it.

Comment: Okay I fixed it :)

Comment: Nice solution. But be aware that when you press Ctrl-C between the `t1.start()` and `stop_threads = True`, the main thread will be aborted and the second thread will run forever, so the application will hang until you kill the Python interpreter. You should catch and handle KeyboardInterrupt if you want the program to be stoppable. Actually, you should catch all possible exceptions, but in this specific example KeyboardInterrupt is the only one I can think of ;-)

Comment: Thanks and yes that is true with all multiprocessing applications.